# Shopware 6 Webpack hot reload in Docker Setup

Tags: docker, nginx, webpack, shopware, shopware6

I am running a **Shopware 6** production instance in a Docker setup using **PHP-FPM** as an app container and **nginx** as reverse proxy. Everything works fine, Shopware is served under https://localhost.

Now I tried to use the built-in hot proxy to use hot reloading when developing on our storefront theme. As the hot proxy is running in the docker container, I had to open the ports and pass the requests to the app container.

Starting the hot proxy using `./bin/watch-storefront.sh` it is starting without errors or warnings:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://localhost:9998/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from https://localhost:9998/
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/dist
Starting the hot reload server: 



 DONE  Compiled successfully in 7420ms                                                                                                                                                                   1:05:40 PM

############
Storefront proxy server started at https://localhost:9998
############
```

When I'm browsing to `http://localhost:9998` or `https://localhost:9998` I just get a `502 Bad Gateway` error. Using the **http** URL, the server writes `Rejecting request "GET localhost/" on proxy server for "localhost:9998"` to the console.

**What I actually did**

I've added ports `9998` and `9999`to my `docker-compose.yml`:

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
  - "9000:3276"
  - "9998:9998"
  - "9999:9999"
```

I also extended my nginx.conf to pass the requests to the app container where the hot reload server is running.

*nginx.conf*

```
server {
    listen 9998 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://naturanum_app:9998;
    }
}

server {
    listen 9999 default_server;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://naturanum_app:9999;
    }
}

server {
    listen 3276 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://naturanum_app:3276;
    }
}
```

Also followed the docs and built JavaScript, Administration and Storefront once before starting the watcher - but it is also not working.

Any ideas how to use the Webpack Hot Proxy inside a Docker container behind a nginx reverse proxy?

Answer (score 2):

You need basically 2 things when working with a **reverse proxy**, a **shop container** and the **watcher**

- docker-compose with **correct ports**
- nginx with correct **configuration**

...here is the solution that works on our end

a) docker-compose

please add the correct ports to your nginx reverse proxy

```
  proxy:
      container_name: proxy
      image: dockware/proxy:latest
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
        - "3000:3000"
        - "8888:8888"
        - "9999:9999"
        - "9998:9998"
      volumes:
        - "./hmr-storefront.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/hmr-storefront.conf"
```

b) nginx proxy conf (hmr-storefront.conf)

This makes sure that https://(mydomain):9998 is loading the watcher

```
server {
    listen                    9998 ssl;
    server_name               default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/selfsigned.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://shop:9998;
        proxy_next_upstream   error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }
}
```

If you now start the watcher (e.g. in dockware => cd /var/www && make watch-storefront), you should be able to consume the watcher version through your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, worthwhile to also name the system you are running on. I had a few issues with Win10, running Docker on WSL2 with the firewall ports being blocked off. Maybe you will need to check the firewall too.

Another resource to look at is the images built by https://dockware.io Their images are robust & configured to run the watchers on most setups. You could check how they build those images on GitHub and see what configurations they use, maybe here would be a good start: https://github.com/dockware/dockware/blob/v1.5.4/template/Dockerfile.global.sh.twig